# Matching keys and values in a string with a regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to figure out how to match a pattern in this string:

```
"Red|1|White|7|Blue|27|Green|56"
```

As you can see, the numbers can be either 1 or 2 digits long (never anything else).

So, if I had a function like this:

```
function GetColorNumber(sColorName){
  var sSearchStr="Red|1|White|7|Blue|27|Green|56";
  var sColorNum;
  var sPattern;

  ...

  return sColorNum;
}
```

How could I use a regular expression in this function return the sColorNum (given an sColorName)?

I've solved this problem using Javascript's `indexOf` and `substring` functions but can't seem to figure out the pattern for an answer using regular expressions. The solution should work for all colors, including the first and last ones.

Comment: Make your life easy and use a proper data structure :)

Comment: Why do you want to use regex for this? In situations where string manipulation and regex will both work, it's almost always better to go with string manip. That isn't *always* true, but the pattern you're working with is very simple and static. It's an excellent candidate for string manipulation, as in **sth**'s answer.

Comment: @Justin or my second example which will work in all browsers

Answer (score 1):

Change the string to

`var colors ={Red:1,White:7,Blue:27,Green:56}`

then you can return

`colors[sColorName]`

Without regEx I would do

`var iColorNum = parseInt(sSearchStr.split(sColorName+"|")[1],10)`

Comment: It's a valid point, but he might not be able to do that. There's no information on where the string is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

It would be simpler to just split the string at `|`:

```
function GetColorNumber(sColorName){
  var sSearchStr="Red|1|White|7|Blue|27|Green|56";
  var parts = sSearchStr.split('|');
  var key = parts.indexOf(sColorName);
  return parts[key+1];
}
```

Comment: which is JS 1.6 https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf - i.e. not compatible with IE < version 9

Answer (score 1):

With a regular expression it could look like this:

```
function GetColorNumber(sColorName){
  var sSearchStr="Red|1|White|7|Blue|27|Green|56";
  var match = RegExp(sColorName + "\\|(\\d+)").exec(sSearchStr);
  return match[1];
}
```

Note that this will not work correctly if the user passes in a string that contains characters that have special meaning in regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regex):

```
var str="Red|1|White|7|Blue|27|Green|56";
var sColorName = "Red"; 
var pat = sColorName + '\\|(\\d{1,2})\\|?';
var re = new RegExp(pat ,"g");
match = re.exec(str);

//match[0] is the full match, match[1] is the color code
document.write(match[1]);
```

or in a shorter fashion:

```
function getColor(colorName, str){
    return (new RegExp(colorName + '\\|(\\d{1,2})\\|?' ,"g")).exec(str)[1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! It works perfectly; Can I ask some questions about the regular expression pattern: (1) why are double backslashes needed ("\\" instead of "\") for it to work? (2) I tested the solution and noticed that without the "?", the pattern will not match the last color; why is that?

Comment: Double slashes are needed in order to escape the escaping backslash :-). The special character backslash needs to be escaped (by a backslash) to be present on the string. As for the question mark, it means the previous term (in this particular case - it may be used differently) may or may not exist. Since your last color does/may not have an ending pipe ("|"), the expression will match it whether or not it exists.

Comment: Thanks very much!! I think the regex solution is the most elegant solution. I wonder if it is more efficient than the solution using the split function proposed by sth.

Comment: I can't comment on that as I'm strongly biased. I prefer Regex over direct string manipulation - specially going back and forth from arrays. Again, not sure about performance and cost.